# Hasura или Elasticsearch для базы на ORACLE?

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, graphql

Уважаемые коллеги, добрый день! Есть база данных почты на ORACLE, необходимо отдавать клиентам данные такие как "отделения, улицы, дома и т.п.". На данном этапе клиенты вытягивают данные через WSO2 методом GET. Периодически бывают накладки со скоростью, данные долго тянутся. В связи с этим, приняли решение рассмотреть HASURA и Elasticsearch. И для начала хочется сравнить их и сформировать "за и против" для каждого решения. искал информацию в гугле, в целом какое-то понимание имеется, но все так же тяжело сравнить эти 2 варианта, быть может кто-то уже работал с HASURA и Elasticsearch и может сказать плюсы и минусы их использования? Данные объемные, к примеру домов больше чем 4 миллиона строк, улиц около 400 тыс, отделений - 25 тыс. Возможно я что-то не досказал, если что спрашивайте, постараюсь максимально объяснить ситуацию!

Comment: 1) Hasura ж вроде для PostgreSQL
2) 4 миллиона домов -- может и не много; смотря что там про дома хранится и как запрашивается

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov 1)Hasura для PL/SQL есть)

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov 2) название, айди улицы, дата создания, дата обновления

Comment: 1) т. е. вы возьмете PostgreSQL с  PL/SQL? 2) байт 100 на дом * 4М = пол гига, не много, вроде, в память влезает

Comment: _Hasura для PL/SQL есть_, а ссылой не поделитесь?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1170592/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85

Comment: @0xdb Вы знаете, нашел типа как плагин дополнительный что бы подключить подобное, но что бы официально, все же я ошибся, нет HASURA для PL/SQL

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Мне же нужно для PL/SQL

Comment: @GermanVaranytsya Я так и понял и поэтому метку убрал, пока не вижу в ней необходимости. Дайте ссылку на неофициальный плагин, что вы нашли. Если не смогу вам помочь в вопросе, то хоть себе возьму на заметку.

Comment: @0xdb https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/4755

Comment: так что тормозит, WSO2 или ORACLE? какие-то конкретные запросы?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov оракл, от этого и wso2 так как идут прямые запросы с базы. конкретные запросы, например с домами сильно грузят сервер, возможно и не так медленно, но хочется быстрее! Возможно если можно будет перекинуть эту базу на какой-то elasticsearch, все будет быстрее?

Comment: Я к тому, что 4М -- это не много. Значит у вас либо очень много запросов, либо они не оптимальные. У нас elasticsearch использовался в проекте, нормально, чтоб в oracle хлам не пихать, но там был больше вопрос в количестве хлама, чем запросов. И еще, целостности между базами не будет: если в одном месте изменить, а потом с другого прочитать.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Много запросов и запросы сами по себе сложные(миллион джоинов), к примеру для того что бы вывести эти 4 млн записей, из-за джоинов оракл шерстит около 50 млн строк, а когда куча клиентов тянут этот запрос одновременно - сильно грузится сервер, по этому и думали найти какое-то решение другое

Comment: денормализовать еще можно -- сделать широкую таблицу под тяжелый запрос, и синхронизировать в нее из оригинальных данных, или из лога изменений; хотя, у оракла была лицензия дорогая, может и разгрузить его.