# Какую БД выбрать для большого количества данных?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, mongodb

Нужно выбрать БД для хранения большого количества данных 1-10 млн.(Храниться будут координаты пользователя и его login). От БД нужно что бы поиск по координатам в определённом радиусе осуществлялся как можно быстрее. Подскажите, если выбрать к примеру Postgre и положить все 10 млн в одну таблицу, не будет ли БД дико тупить при поиске по таблице? Или нужно смотреть в сторону NoSQL?

Comment: 1-10 млн. чего? Записей? Так это крошечный объём данных. У меня в одном из проектов, например, выборки из таблицы с 23 миллиардами записей укладываются в миллисекунды.

Comment: @viktor-ovsienko предлагаю сделать две тестовые таблицы, набить их рандомными данными и напишите тесты. Можно будет сделать измерялку времени под ваши нужды.

Comment: *От БД нужно что бы поиск по координатам в определённом радиусе осуществлялся как можно быстрее.* Наплюйте на радиус и проверяйте на попадание в квадрат - это взлетит на почти любой СУБД, даже без spatial indices.

Comment: https://eax.me/postgis/

Answer (score 4):

10 млн. записей это немного. Postgres спокойно пережует. 10 млн. возьмет даже SQLite или Access/Excel

Много это от 10 млрд. записей.

Comment: 10 млн можно про100 в память загнать.

Answer (score 3):

Так как у вас данные структурированы и имеют определённую структуру, есть смысл пользоваться SQL базами данных так как SQL универсальный язык запросов, который используется всеми реляционными системами. По поводу количества данных, так СУБД и создаются специально для этих целей не важно SQL или NoSQL.

Прочитать статью по NoSQL можно [тут](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/113232/), о выборе [SQL или NoSQL](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/324936/)

PS. а ещё у PostgreSQL есть такое

> [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) is a spatial database extender for PostgreSQL
> object-relational database. It adds support for geographic objects
> allowing location queries to be run in SQL.